# Re-write needed

Tags: fiction

Joshua heard himself say, “I’m heading over to Jason’s.”  He felt his footsteps leading towards the door.  Joshua opened and shut the door in a daze, not knowing where his steps would lead him.

Comment: Welcome to the site, rccola1986! Unfortunately, proofreading or re-write requests are off-topic here, as such question are very unlikely to help anyone else. If you can rephrase your question so that it could help other people with the same problem, we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess normally this site doesn't answer questions unlikely to help more than the asker (OP). But welcome! Also, you didn't ask a question. However, I'll interpret and generalize to *"How do I make a limited third-person point of view not sound monotonous? Here is my sample:"*.

1. You can reverse the subject and predicate or just put the subject after the verb.
2. You can start a sentence with a prepositional or participial (*-ing*) phrase.
3. You can pair a quote with an action to minimize the use of "said."
4. You can use adverbs to give your storytelling "body."

In your passage, I like the sleepwalking/psychedelia feel. As an aside, sleepwalkers generally have no awareness or recollection of their actions. With third-person limited point of view, it would (have to) be altered consciousness. How about:

**Joshua felt the urge to move; he knew not where. Inspiration led him to the door but all else was confusion. "I'm heading over to Jason's" came a voice from every place and no place at once. Shutting the door behind him, he tentatively stepped out into the world.**